# Firebase Retrieving and inserting in tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I need Help retrieving a child and adding it in a tableview. The child is called "Title" and is a subclass of "Post". I've successfully retrieved all the Post and printed it but I don't know how to just put the "Title" in my tableview.

```
var posts = [postStruct]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

        print(rest.value!)


                //need help here! I want to put the title which is a child of "Post"






        }


    })


}






override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
    return cell!
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts")    

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    print(snapshot.childrenCount)

    for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

        guard let value = rest.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> else { continue }

        guard let  title = value["Title"] as? String else { continue }

        let post = postStruct(title: title)

        self.posts.append(post)
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```